# Unable to deploy flask application on azure web apps

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-devops

I have been trying to deploy a simple python application on azure web apps.
All the tutorials I read suggest that flask application can be only be deployed with linux web apps.

When I try to do it with azure linux web app ,and set the deployment method , the python build is not supported.
The only options shown are for the build are node, php ruby and asp.net

I did not find any tutorial that how it can be done on windows web apps.

My build.yml file is as follows:

```
variables:
  ConnectedServiceName: 'azure_first_connection'
  WebAppName: 'STABACKEDNTRAIN'
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.6'
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
  displayName: 'Install tools'

- script: pip install -r requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install requirements'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    verbose: # Optional

- task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: Azure App Service Deploy
  inputs:
    appType: webAppLinux
    RuntimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.6'
    ConnectedServiceName: $(ConnectedServiceName)
    WebAppName: $(WebAppName)
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'


    StartupCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 application'
```

The code of my application.py is

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I am totally new to azure web apps. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try below guides. Any updates?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT . Thank you so much for your efforts. Yes I have followed the second guide URL word by word still was not able to deploy a simple application. My pipeline succeeds with every step completed. But as soon as I hit the URL I get application error. I am not able to diagnose what is wrong.

Comment: Can you share your build yaml? And also visit this site (https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net) to check if the code is deployed to azure web apps. And make sure the the start up command points to the right startup .py file.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Please have a look at my build.yml file. The code is there and it is pointing to the right startup file

Comment: I tested your build yaml and find the `StartupCommand` doesnot specified the Flask app object. Please check below my update

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I have tried that as well. No luck

Comment: Sorry one thing i forget to mention, You also need add input `includeRootFolder: false ` for your archive task. Check below my update.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Tried that too. Still no luck. When I hit the endpoint I get :( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Am I missing something in the configuration? As of now I am using a normal hello world flask application. Still not able to reach the endpoint

Comment: I donot think additional configuration is needed. Could you share your code application.py?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202247/discussion-between-shivangi-bhardwaj-and-levi-lu-msft).

Answer (score 0):

There are some tutorials available on Microsoft sites about how to deploy Python apps on Azure web App.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops#provision-the-target-azure-app-service) is a guide showing you how to deploy to azure web app from azure portal.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-devops-project-and-connect-to-azure) is a guide showing you how to deploy python apps to Azure App Service from Azure Pipelines

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-03) is a tutorial about how to deploy python apps from VScode

**Addition:**
StartupCommand should point to the right the Flask app object in the right start up .py file. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-04#flask-startup-commands) for more information about startup command.

If your Flask app whose main module is application.py and the Flask app object in that file is named app. The command should look like below.

`StartupCommand: 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 application:app'`

**Update:**

To void including source folder being included in the deployed artifacts, You aslo need to specifically set `includeRootFolder` to false. Or your project will be deployed to a **s** folder under **wwwroot** , `wwwroot/s/`

```
 - task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Application$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
    includeRootFolder: false
```

Hope you find above helpful.

Comment: Hi @Shivangi Bhardwaj Havenot heard from you for a while, How was it going with this case, did you finally get it working?